# Force upper case on input

Tags: acumatica

I have an input mask that is supposed to convert to upper case.  In fact, the display changes to upper case when focus is moved off the field but the data is still in lower case in the database.  How can I force the save in uppercase also.

```
    #region PartnerID
    public abstract class partnerID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    protected string _PartnerID;
    [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Partner")]
    public virtual string PartnerID { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Just to double-check, do you have `PXMaskEdit` input control defined in Aspx for the PartnerID field?

Comment: No I do not.  I only setup the default values.  I will look at the options for the field on the form.

Comment: This works to get the uppercase, but I lose the ability to include underscores in the value.  This is definitely required as I have to match values in another system.  There is no segmented key to update the prompt character since this is a custom table.  Can I define a prompt character for it?

Comment: I can't seem to get the auto upper case conversion along with the ability to include underscores.  I can use the text edit field in the aspx page and a toUpper() in the rowSelected event.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InputMask set for PXDBStringAttribute will not make any effect without the use of PXMaskEdit in Aspx. Try to recreate input control in Layout Editor and test the results with PartnerID defined as an auto-implemented property.

To specify a different prompt character, you can set an HTML code of the new prompt character to the PromptChar property of PXMaskEdit in Aspx:

`<px:PXMaskEdit ID="edPartnerID" runat="server" DataField="PartnerID" PromptChar="&#42;" />`

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to be helpful.

Comment: Ruslan, see my comments above about underscores. I should have put them on this answer.

Comment: Jerry, please see my updated answer above for an example of how to specify a different prompt character for PXMaskEdit.

Answer (score 0):

There are other (better?) way to achieve this but I believe the C# property setter could work:

```
#region PartnerID
public abstract class partnerID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
protected string _PartnerID;
[PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
[PXDefault()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Partner")]
public virtual string PartnerID 
{ 
   get
   {
      return this._PartnerID;
   },
   set
   {
      this._PartnerID = value.ToUpper();
   } 
}
#endregion
```

Comment: I will try this.  Sometimes the simplest way is the best.  I assumed the >CCCCCCC... would also automatically convert it to upper.